# ESXi VM unable to communicate with physical LAN

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have set up a Windows 2019 VM on a ESXi 7.0 host with basic network topology as follows:

- VM connected to vSwitch0 (via a vNIC added to the VM)  with uplink to the only physical NIC on the host.
- The host & another physical PC running Windows 10 is connected to a router
- Router (192.168.1.1) Host (192.168.1.2) PC (192.168.1.3)  VM (192.168.1.4 - statically set on the vNIC on the VM)
- Physical NIC is a USB ethernet adapter named by ESXi as vusb0

From the VM, for some unknown reason, I am unable to ping the physical PC (and the from the physical PC - I cannot ping the VM)

However, I can ping the host from VM and physical PC.

Am I missing any obvious - to get the VM to communicate with devices outside its vSwitch0 ?

Do I have to set an IP range on the vNIC itself - if so, how would I go about doing this ?

Any suggestions are appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per you exaplanation and image it's sound that everything is ok. Did you try to disable firewall on VM and physical pc?

Comment: Disabling the firewalls got the ping working as expected - should have checked that duh. Thanks for suggestion !